# Module names with swig

Tags: c++, perl, swig

I am trying to use swig to create perl modules.

```
%module mymodule
```

works but

```
%module mymoduele::mymodule
```

does not work. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: "does not work" - can you please be more specific? Maybe the problem is that you forgot the quotes, i.e. `%module "mymodule::mymodule"`?

Comment: Not sure if this could be a duplicate of [Generate a perl module with a separate namespace using SWIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16146606/generate-a-perl-module-with-a-separate-namespace-using-swig)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing double quotes around the module name. According to [the documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Perl5.html):

> To give your module a nested namespace simply provide the fully
>   qualified name in your `%module` directive:
>
> %module "Foo::Bar::Baz"
>
> NOTE: the double quotes are necessary.